# SQL INNER JOIN for basic request

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem:

- Table #1: Article ID, Job Nr
- Table #2: Job Nr, Customer Job Nr
- Table #3: Customer Job Nr, Article ID, Price

Code:

```
SELECT 
    Table3.Price, ...
FROM 
    Table1
INNER JOIN ?
```

How can I complete this inner join, so that the price of the article is in the results? There is more than one Price per Article ID, but combinations of Article ID and Customer Job Nr or Job Nr are unique. There is exactly one Job Nr for every Customer Job Nr. I don’t want to change anything in select or from, since this is just a part of a much larger query and changes there would mess things up.

I beg your pardon for such a beginner question, but I just couldn’t get it right.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using Oracle 19c ANSI , you can use 

SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1,Table2 t2, Table3 t3
where t1.jobNr= t2.jobNr
and t2.CustomerJobNr = t3.CustomerJobNr
AND t1.ArticleId = t3.ArticleId;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to ascertain with certainty without seeing sample data sets and, but if your conditions are correct:

> "combinations of Article ID and Customer Job Nr or Job Nr are unique"

The following query should yield the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT distinct
    Table3.Price, Table1.ArticleID, Table1.Job_Nr, t2.CustomerJobNr,
FROM 
    Table1 JOIN Table2 AND Table3
    ON (Table1.Job_Nr = Table2.Job_Nr or t2.CustomerJobNr = t3.CustomerJobNr)
    and Table1.ArticleID = Table3.ArticleID
```

Again, this may not yield the expected result if your stated assumptions are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do this with multiple `JOIN`s to your target tables.

For example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ArticleId = Table2.ArticleId
INNER JOIN Table3
ON Table2.CustomerJobNr = Table3.CustomerJobNr
AND Table1.ArticleId = Table2.ArticleId
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ArticleId = Table2.ArticleId
JOIN Table3
ON Table2.CustomerJobNr = Table3.CustomerJobNr
AND Table1.ArticleId = Table2.ArticleId
```